# How to select top rows from a table when grouping data by hours?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table in SQL Server Management that contains error counts by hours. The table uses has four main columns Errors, StartTime, EndTime and Count. Is there a way I can select the top 1 error or top 5 errors that occur every hour?

A typical entry would look something like this:

| Error | StartTime | EndTime | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| error 1 | 2022-06-27 00:00:00 | 2022-06-27 01:00:00 | 8 |
| error 2 | 2022-06-27 00:00:00 | 2022-06-27 01:00:00 | 9 |
| error 1 | 2022-06-27 01:00:00 | 2022-06-27 02:00:00 | 1 |
| error 3 | 2022-06-27 01:00:00 | 2022-06-27 02:00:00 | 19 |

For example, in this case, `error 2` would be the top error between hours 0 and 1, and `error 3` would be the top error between hours 1 and 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT EndTime,
        Error,
        [Count],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY EndTime ORDER BY [Count] DESC
            ) AS rn
    FROM TABLENAME
    )
SELECT EndTime,
    Error,
    [Count],
    rn
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 5
ORDER BY EndTime,
    [Count] DESC
```

You can try here with [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c2570f0159874ae4878d49e3997b941d)

Comment: You're right about the query not working.  I used a table I already had but screwed up the script when changing names around.  As for the rn <=5, he asked for top 1 or top 5, so I went with top 5

Comment: haha so they did. :P Without the group by this is a +1 from me.

Comment: @SeanLange Fixed it.  And added a dbfiddle link to boot

Comment: @Kevin I tested the query against my database and it work as required! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have written a solution for you. Please check it , i hope it solves your problem

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT *,
     dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY StartTime,EndTime ORDER BY Count DESC) AS 
rn
 FROM Table
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: what if te timestamp don't are identical?